# Twitter log in website failure 415

Tags: twitter-login

[TwitterKit] did encounter error with message "Error obtaining user auth token.": Error Domain=TWTRLogInErrorDomain Code=-1 "Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings}

Comment: [try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beCdi.png) don't forget update button

Answer (score 2):

i solved this by inputting twitterkit-xxx[appkey]:// on CallbackURLs in website https://apps.twitter.com

Comment: what do you mean by xxx after twitterkit- ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your app in https://apps.twitter.com and 
[enter your callback URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njL0i.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should add your callback url in your twitter app. See the image below.

[image]